# mod_auth_openidc with Apache2.4 reverse proxy

Tags: apache2.4, mod-auth-openidc

I'm trying to setup SSO with OpenID for Centreon web app.
Here is the architecture : 
**Apache 2.4** (windows) with **mod_auth_openidc 2.3.9**
**Centreon 2.8.17**

I want only one vhost to authenticate through SSO so I added all the openidc conf to the vhost.conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.com

<Location />
AuthType openid-connect
Require valid-user
</Location>

OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://openid.com/fss/.well-known/openid-configuration
OIDCClientID MY-Centreon
OIDCClientSecret abcdefghijklmnop
OIDCProviderTokenEndpointAuth client_secret_post
OIDCRedirectURI https://myserver.com/ssoredirect
OIDCScope "openid profile"
OIDCCryptoPassphrase mypassphrase
OIDCAuthNHeader MY_HEADER
OIDCRemoteUserClaim sub
OIDCClaimPrefix myprefix_

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://10.10.10.10/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.10.10/

</VirtualHost>
```

On Centreon the only thing we have to do is to give the name of the HTTP Header that contains the user login (see [documentation](https://documentation.centreon.com/docs/centreon/en/2.8.x/howto/sso.html))  :
[CENTREON SSO CONF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuycN.png)

When I go to https://myserver.com it redirects me to the SSO login page. From here i'm able to identify and I'm redirected to Centreon but not logged in so it redirects me to the Centreon login page.
In the centreon **login.log** I have :

```
[WEB] No contact found with this login : ''
```

It shows that Centreon does not receive anything in the "MY_HEADER" header, thus SSO authentication is not working.

***Additional information:*** (don't know if it can be useful) :
My Apache reverse proxy is listening on http (80) behind a load balancer that listens on HTTPS (443) and transfers it to the server on HTTP (80)

**My question** :
I'm not sure about the header name that contains the username. In the above config, can somebody confirm that Centreon should receive a header "MY_HEADER" containing the username?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have this message, it means that the user maybe doesn't exist into "Configuration > Users > Contacts / Users".

Maybe you need to connect your LDAP server and enable "Auto Import" user to import missing users automatically.

Also long time ago there was a bug where you had to fill any email address in the filed 'SSO blacklist client addresses' otherwise it will send this error [WEB] No contact found with this login : '', you can try this.

Comment: The user exists in the Centreon user base. Same login i double checked.
the "SSO blacklist client addresses" is for IP address, not email address. I tried to populate this field with an IP address we are not using but it still returns "No contact found with this login ''